# How do I find the number of group homomorphisms from $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

How do I find the number of group homomorphisms from the symmetric group $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: By the way, "the options I am given..." isn't really a part of the question from the mathematical point of view, so it probably shouldn't be posted here.  If I think I can prove that the answer is 7, I will answer that way regardless of any instructions that may have been given to you by a third party for whatever reason :)

Answer (score 17):

The kernel of a homomorphism must be a normal subgroup of the inverse image. Simply $S_3$ has 3 normal subgroups which are $\{e\}$, $A_3$, and $S_3$.

Let $\phi : S_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6 $.

Then possible kernels are $\{e\}$, $A_3$, and $S_3$.

Firstly, try $\{e\}$. By First Isomorphism Theorem, $S_3/{e}$ which is $S_3$ itself, $S_3\simeq \phi(S_3)$. The order of $S_3$ is 6 and observe that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has the same order. Thus, it yields $\phi(S_3)=\mathbb{Z}_6$. However, $S_3$ is not abelian although $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is. It is contradiction. Therefore, $\ker\phi$ cannot be $\{e\}$.

Secondly, let's check for $\ker\phi=S_3$. Then you can map every element of $S_3$ to the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, that is, $\phi(s)=0$, $\forall s \in S_3$.

The last option is $\ker\phi = A_3$, therefore the order of the factor group $S_3/A_3$ is $2$. First isomorphism theorem gives us: $S_3/A_3 \simeq \phi(S_3)$, then $\phi(S_3)$ is $\{3,0\}. $

$\phi(s)= 0$ if $s \in A_3$.

Otherwise, $\phi(s)= 3$

As a conclusion, the answer is $2$.

Comment: bt in solution set answer is 1, thats why i am confused.

Comment: can it be possible that the trivial one should not be taken into account, otherwise I dont see any explanation, I'm quite what I've explained.

Comment: Shouldn't the first sentence be: "The kernel of a homomorphism must be the inverse image of a normal subgroup.", instead of the current "The kernel of a homomorphism must be a normal subgroup of the inverse image."?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is Abelian, and $S_3$ is non-Abelian.  What does this tell us about the kernel of any homomorphism from $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?  Can we guarantee that certain elements inside $S_3$ must lie in the kernel?  How many should there be?  Now use this to count the total number of homomorphisms.

**Added:** $S_3$ consists of three elements of order $2$, two elements of order $3$, and the identity.  The elements of order $2$ and $3$ do not commute.  What possible places in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ could I send an element of order $2$?  What about the two elements of order $3$?

Comment: Can you plz explain how to find out the kernel of any homomorphism from S3 to Z/6Z?

Comment: @AlkaGoyal I added some more information

Comment: It is still confusing for me,, can u plz further elaborate it?

Comment: @AlkaGoyal The kernel of any homomorphism is defined as the set of elements which it maps to the identity. As for how the added hint helps: if, e.g., $s \in S_3$ is a permutation which swaps two of the three elements, then no homomorphism can map $s$ to 2. Why? Because $s^2$ is the identity in $S_3$, and $2^2$ is not the identity in Z/6Z.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi: G\rightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism.  Suppose that $H$ is abelian.  Can you prove that the commutator subgroup of $G$ must be contained in $\text{ker}\phi$?  (Recall: the commutator subgroup of $G$, denoted $G'$, is the subgroup generated by $\{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh : g,h \in G \}$.)

> By the first isomorphism theorem, $G/\text{ker}\phi\cong H$.  Write $\text{ker}\phi$ as $K$.  Since $H$ is abelian, so is $G/K$, and thus $(gK)(hK)=(hK)g(K) \Leftrightarrow (gh)K=(hg)K \Leftrightarrow (g^{-1}h^{-1}gh)K= K$ we have $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh\in K$.  Since this is true for all $g,h\in G$, we have that $G'\leqslant K$.  (Of course, we can simply do these steps backwards to show that the converse is true, so in fact $G'\leqslant K$ *if and only if* $G/K$ is abelian.)

By a simple computation, $S_3'$ is the subgroup of rotations of order $3$.  I claim that $\phi:S_3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ cannot be surjective.  Why?

> Since $[S_3:S_3']=2$ and $S_3'\leqslant \text{ker}\phi$, $S_3/\text{ker}\phi$ has order *at most* $2$.

With this information, you should be able to deduce which subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ can be an image of a homomorphism from $S_3$.  From this you can easily count the number of homomorphisms.