# For which $n$ and $k$ are there nontrivial homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

The question [How do I find the number of group homomorphisms from $S_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261587/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-group-homomorphisms-from-s-3-to-mathbbz-6-math) got me curious and thinking about the following:

For which $n$ and $k$ are there nontrivial homomorphisms from the symmetric group $S_n$ to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ of order $k$? I'm thinking it might be an open problem. Is this a problem with a known solution? If so, how can we prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: For $n\ge 5$, the only normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, so $k=2$. Then one can figure out $n<5$ by force.

Comment: @ElliotG: technically, one would have $2$ *divides* $k$, since the sign morphism onto $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ can be composed with the injection of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ into any cyclic group of even order.

Comment: Since $\mathbb C^*$ contains a copy of every cyclic group, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3626782/589

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can proceed as follows. Let $f:S_n\to \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$.

We know that any two transpositions are conjugate in $S_n$, so they have conjugate images by $f$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, it follows that two transpositions have same image.

Let $\tau$ be a fixed transposition. Then $2f(\tau)=f(\tau^2)=f(Id)=0$, so $f(\tau)$ has order $1$ or $2$. In the first case, the image of any transposition is trivial, and since they generate $S_n$, $f$ is trivial. In the second case, which may happen only if $k$ is even, a transposition is mapped to the only element of order $2$ of $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$.

In this case, $f(\sigma)$ is $0$ is $\sigma$ is even, and $\overline{k/2}$ if $\sigma$ is odd. In other words, $f$ will be the composition of the signature morphism with the morphism $\theta: \{\pm 1\}\to \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ sending $-1$ to $\overline{k/2}$.

**Conclusion**. If $k$ is odd, there is no nontrivial morphism. If $k$ is even, there is exactly one nontrivial morphism (which is the signature in disguise)

Comment: Hi ! This is a refreshing approach. Your conclusion holds for any choice of $n \geq 1$, correct ?

Comment: Yup! Say $n\geq 2$ to have at least one transposition.

Comment: Note there is nothing original in this approach. This is the same approach used when trying to determine morphisms $S_n\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ (yielding the signature). In general, it is natural to try to guess the image of a set of generators. The fact you wan to exploit also conjugacy classes here is because the target is abelian, so two conjugate elements will have the same image.