# homomorphisms from S3 to Z24

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Can someone verify if my part solution is correct and help me complete it?

I found normal subgroups of S3: {e}, {S3}, {e, (123), (132)}

If kernel of homomorphism is {S3} then we have trivial homomorphism

If kernel is {e, (123), (132)} then we have two homomorphism because natural projection p from S3 to S3/kernel gives 2 elements group which is isomorphic to Z2 (g) and there are 2 homomorphisms from Z2 to Z24 (h1 and h2) and we get our desired homomorphism by composition h1gp and h2gp

If kernel is {e} then image of homomorphisms have order 6 and its a subgroup of Z24 so image is {0,4,8,12,16,20} and I do not know what to do next.

Comment: The kernel cannot be trivial because the codomain is abelian but the domain isn’t.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). For the question, preceed as explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261587/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-group-homomorphisms-from-s-3-to-mathbbz-6-math) and the linked ones.

Answer (score 0):

$$S_3=\langle a,b\mid a^3,b^2,aba^{-2}b\rangle. $$

There's two.

They can be specified using that $$S_3=\langle (12),(123)\rangle.$$

- $$(123)\to e,(12)\to \bar{12},$$
  and
- $$(123)\to e,(12)\to e.$$

There's no embedding because any subgroup of an abelian group is abelian.

There's none with kernel $S_2$, because $S_2$ isn't normal.